# Google Custom Search Link Attribute Not Setting Properly

Tags: javascript, google-custom-search

I am trying to accomplish the simple task of giving the user a checkbox in which they are able to set the link target for the results on a Google Custom Search "widget" (if you will). But for some reason, the appropriate attribute that I am required to set for the search "widget" to change this according to https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element#supported_attributes is not doing anything at all. See for yourself below.

```js
var ntChk = document.getElementById('ntChk')

ntChk.onclick = function () {
    if (ntChk.checked == true) {
        document.getElementById('searchresults').setAttribute('data-linkTarget', '_blank');
    } else {
        document.getElementById('searchresults').setAttribute('data-linkTarget', '_self');
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Google Custom Search Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="checkbox" id="ntChk" /> Open results in new tab
  <script async src="https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=ea0629e3e0cd64c16"></script>
<div class="gcse-search" id="searchresults"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried directly setting the target by grabbing the class of all the result titles and using `setAttribute('', '')` on them, but then my browser gave me an error saying that this operation was not allowed. So, I tried using the `.target = ""` method but this produced no result at all (not even visually through Inspect Element).

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't see the documentation say anywhere that you could toggle this dynamically, _after_ the widget has already been rendered.

Comment: _"I tried directly"_ - a mere verbal description is not enough for us to be able to tell what might have gone wrong; _show code_ when you talk about something you tried.

Comment: @CBroe You are absolutely correct. I never thought that being able to dynamically set something would ever be a question, but I guess it was.

Comment: @CBroe I think you're over thinking it. Don't pay attention to the word "directly", just understand that I grabbed all the result titles by their class name and tried to use setAttribute() on them.